# Is it possible to inherit old-style class from ECMAScript 6 class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

When running the following code on Node.js 4.2.1:

```js
'use strict';

var util = require('util');

class MyClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

function MyDerived() {
  MyClass.call(this, 'MyDerived');
}

util.inherits(MyDerived, MyClass);

var d = new MyDerived();
```

I get the following error:

```
constructor(name) {
         ^

TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I wonder if it is at all possible to inherit old-style JavaScript "classes" from ECMAScript 6 classes? And, if possible, then how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's not really a way out once you've opted in to `class` syntax.

The problem is that inheritance in ES6 is done by late-initialising the `this` keyword with the return value from `super()`, which is a constructor call like with `new`. The old idiom of "applying" ([`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)) the parent constructor on the currently "uninitialised" child instance does **work no more**.

What you can still do is to resort to "parasitic inheritance" - you'll have to explicitly construct the instance, extend it, and `return` it:

```
function MyDerived() {
  var derived = new MyClass('MyDerived');
  … // set up properties
  return derived;
}
```

When you do this with `new MyClass`, you won't get the prototype set up correctly however. For that, you will need to use the new ES6 [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) function, which takes the child class as an optional third parameter:

```
function MyDerived() {
  var derived = Reflect.construct(MyClass, ['MyDerived'], new.target||MyDerived);
  … // set up properties
  return derived;
}
```

This has the additional benefit that `MyDerived` doesn't need to be called with `new` any more (as long as you supply `MyDerived` when `new.target` is empty).