# How do javascripts extends work?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, extends

**Update** : Post by @Bergi on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369131/is-it-possible-to-inherit-old-style-class-from-ecmascript-6-class-in-javascript) explains the need to use `Reflect.construct` instead of just calling the parent constructor. This shifts the question to "What's the technical difference between Constructor.call() and Reflect.construct()". Thanks for all the comments.

For quite a while I have been extending all sorts of types by setting the prototype of my new prototype to the one that is to be extended. E.g. If I wanted to extend the class "Person" i'd create my extending prototype by calling `NewType.prototype=Object.create(Person.prototype);` for something like:

```
const B = function(){
    return A.call(this);
};

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

B.prototype.extra_method = function(){
    console.log('hello');
}
```

Recently I have noticed tho that this method is not as capable as the [ES6 class extends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends). For example if I wanted to extend a builtin type, I can only really do that with the class extends keyword. Why is that?

**Example A** (does not work):

```
const ArrayExt = function(){
    this.extra_variable = 'hello!';
    return Array.call(this,...arguments); 
}

ArrayExt.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

ArrayExt.prototype.extra_method = function(){
    console.log('Method called!');
}

var inst = new ArrayExt(1,2,3);

inst.push(4);
inst.length == 4 //seems to work right?

inst.extra_method == undefined //not included
inst.extra_variable == undefined //not included (why?)
```

**Example B** (works):

```
const ArrayExt = class extends Array{
    constructor(){
        super(...arguments);
        this.extra_variable = 'Hello!';
    }

    extra_method(){
        console.log('I actually am here now!');
    }
};

var inst = new ArrayExt(1,2,3);

inst.push(4);
inst.length == 4 //works
inst.extra_variable == 'Hello!' //works
inst.extra_method() //'I actually am here now!' works
```

Comment: classes and extends are just syntactic sugar to old style "classes" and "extends" . If you use a transpiler to convert ES6 to older syntax then you'll confirm this is more or less accurate

Comment: so then how come I can only extend builtin types (Array,Function) with the extends keyword?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369131/is-it-possible-to-inherit-old-style-class-from-ecmascript-6-class-in-javascript looks relevant. Also your question is asking the opposite of what your comment is saying.

Comment: How so? Thanks for the link, this really does seem relevant.

Comment: You are saying that you can only extend `Array` and `Function` using the `extends` keyword (which is not true, the old style should still work https://jsfiddle.net/z63qsrk0/) but your comment says that you cannot use the `extends` keyword on any built in type other than Array and Function (which may be true not sure)

Comment: I tested your fiddle. It only works at first glance, then I noticed that the extra_method is not included in the object. It seems to simply ignore the extending prototype. i.e. b.extra_method == undefined.
Also I think you might misread what I wrote. Atleast if "not as capable as ES6 class extends" means "not as powerful as ES6 class extends" (not a native speaker).

Comment: @apokryfos no his question is completely logical.

Comment: *“Why is that?”* No particular reason for being able to do it – you just can, now. I’d consider it another ES6 mistake.

Comment: I gave the previously posted thread a more thorough read, and it seems that what I am doing is "parasitic inheritance", I was missing the use of Reflect.construct, which works (!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the technical difference between Constructor.call() and Reflect.construct()

It's a different usage of the function object. It's the same as the difference between `Example()` and `new Example()`.

The two expressions always did different things, resolving to two different internal methods (named `[[call]]` and `[[construct]]`) that an object could have. ES6 just introduced new types of functions where only one of them works (arrows, methods: call; `class` constructors: construct). Functions created from  `function` syntax always did enable both (even when it was not desirable).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bergi. I assumed that the new operator just calls the constructor-function with a new instance, as in myType.call(Object.create(myType.prototype)). Is there a special reason for the new operator not doing just that instead of calling this internal [[construct]] method?

Comment: @JohnSmith Not exactly. `new` is calling the [[construct]] method, which was doing this instance construction and function body execution (plus some things about the return value) with old `function` constructors. Some builtins (like `Date` or `HTMLElement`) did work differently the whole time - and now with ES6 they are extensible.