# Extending a "function class" using a `class`

Tags: javascript

I have some old code and some new code. The old code uses `function` to define "classes". The new code uses `class` to define them.

I'm trying to extend an old-style "function class" using a new `class` without having to refactor either one.

### Background

I started with something like this:

```js
const OldClass = function(){};
OlClass.prototype.constructor = OldClass;
```

If I wanted to extend it using a class defined through the same pattern, it would go like this:

```js
const OldBase = function() {
  this.value = 'OldBase'
};
OldBase.prototype.constructor = OldBase;
OldBase.prototype.fromOldBase = function() {
  return 'from: ' + this.value;
};

const OldClass = function() {
  OldBase.call(this);
};
Object.setPrototypeOf(OldClass.prototype, OldBase.prototype)
OldClass.prototype.constructor = OldClass;

const x = new OldClass();
console.log(x.fromOldBase()); // prints: "from: OldBase"
```

### Current code

What I have now, looks like:

```js
class NewBase {
  constructor() {
    this.value = 'NewBase';
  }
  fromOldBase() {
    return 'from: ' + this.value;
  }
}

const OldClass = function() {
  NewBase.call(this);
};
Object.setPrototypeOf(OldClass.prototype, NewBase.prototype);
OldClass.prototype.constructor = OldClass;

const x = new OldClass();
console.log(x.fromOldBase()); // prints: from NewBase
```

But I'm getting an error:

```bash
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor NewBase cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I need to call `NewBase.constructor` because it sets `this.value`. But the "syntactic sugar" of `class` isn't letting me access it. I have also tried:

```js
NewBase.prototype.constructor.call(this);
```

...but I get the same error.

### Other considerations

- It will, unfortunately, be easier to refactor the `NewBase` than it will the `OldClass`, so I'm looking for suggestions before I take that leap.
- I thought about moving everything from `NewBase.prototype.constructor` into an `NewBase.prototype.init` that I could call from `OldClass.prototype.constructor`, but that sounds uglier than just refactoring `NewBase` to use the `function` pattern.

Comment: Can you use `super()`?

Comment: Why not use `class` syntax for everything? `class OldClass extends NewBase`?

Comment: I suspect you want to unify the method of creating objects. If that's the case I suggest to consider a class with factory methods.

Comment: @Barmar `super` won't work because that is part of the `class` syntax. As I mentioned, I'm looking to avoid the work of refactoring either class, but I'll do it if there's no solution here.

Comment: @RudyMartin If I'm understanding your suggestion, I think it aligns with the `init` method I considered at the end of my post. I could try that, but it means `NewBase.prototype.constructor` simply calls `init`, which is fine, but less syntactically pleasant.

Comment: "*I'm trying to extend an old-style "function class" using a new `class` without having to refactor either one.*" - that's easy, `class NewClass extends OldBase {…}`. However your "*current code*" is trying to do exactly the opposite (changing to `NewBase` while still extending `OldClass` from it). Which one is it that you want to do?

Comment: If you want/need to use ES6 `class` syntax for the base class, then this becomes a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369131/is-it-possible-to-inherit-old-style-class-from-ecmascript-6-class-in-javascript

Comment: I think I see it now, you don't want to modify "OldClass" which is the real problem (ie: large codebase). BTW your second code should output "from newBase" if it could work. IMHO if I were in your shoes, before doing anything I would worry about code coverage with unit testing.

Comment: @RudyMartin I corrected the copy/paste error. I don't see how coverage and unit testing would help, as these are only simplified examples. My actual code is well-tested/-covered.

Comment: @Bergi I think you're right that this is a duplicate of the question you posted. I want `OldClass` to _inherit from_ `NewBase`. I'll look into your answer there, and this question can be closed as a duplicate.